# IntelliJ Properties File when save auto convert unicode to Capital Letter

Tags: intellij-idea, utf-8

I am migrating from Eclipse to IntelliJ, and I have some properties file storing different languages.

Previously, all my properties file use UTF-8 with lower case letter to save the words.

However when using IntelliJ, when I update the property file, all values in the properties file change to upper case letter with UFT-8 format.

I may not know much about UTF-8 syntax, and not sure whether there are any difference between upper and lowercase UTF-8 encoded word.

However, as the project is developed for years, I would not like to change the properties file from lower case UTF-8 to uppercase UTF-8.e.g. `\u4e0d` to `\u4E0D`.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve such issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Just find out the answer from the official webpage of IntelliJ.

> It is possible to encode non-ASCII symbols using both uppercase and lowercase hex sequences (for example, \u00E3 and \u00e3). By default, only uppercase sequences are enabled. To use lowercase hex sequences, set the idea.native2ascii.lowercase property in the idea.properties file to true.

Source: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/resource-bundle.html